# Is “so” always accompanied by “that”?

Tags: word-usage

In the following question, why can’t answer three be the right answer to fill in the blank? The correct answer is supposed to be choice one.

> The new skyscraper was `____________` the buildings around it look like dollhouses.
>
> 1. so tall that it made
> 2. so tall and it therefore making
> 3. so tall, making
> 4. tall so much because it made
> 5. this tall, it made

Comment: (C) is incorrect because the new skyscraper was so tall that it made the buildings around look like dollhouses.

Comment: *The building was very tall, making...* would be good English: presumably this is what OP is thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

Despite its common use as an intensifier

- *I'm **so** irritated at him!*

*so* is actually the first part of a *so...that* equative construction, and takes a *that* complement.

The intensifier usage is just a matter of dropping a complement describing an outcome.
Since there are many expressions available, dropping it causes no loss of information.

- *I'm so irritated at him that I'm getting a migraine/I can't stand it/I'll kill him.*

The point to remember is it's the *so...**that*** construction,
so it requires (or invites) a [tensed *that*-complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf)
(*that* can get deleted, so make sure there's a subject and a tensed verb phrase in the complement).

That would be #1.
 #3 contains no *that*, no subject, and no tense (gerunds are untensed);
ergo, not a tensed clause.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're using "it made the buildings around it look like dollhouses" as a description of how tall the building was, you have to use "so" with a finite verb: *so tall that it made*, or just *so tall it made*.

If you say *The new skyscraper was so tall, making the buildings around it look like dollhouses*, you're making two separate statements. First, you're saying that *the new skyscraper was so tall* ("so tall" here would be a somewhat informal way of saying "astonishingly tall"), and second, you're saying that the skyscraper made the buildings around it look like dollhouses.